# create regex to accept blank/space or decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to create regex in c# which return true for value having blank/space/null or decimal value with 2 decimal points.So not to accept other than that.

Answer (score 2):

Although probably not the most efficient, this regular expression should do what you want:

```
^((\d+[\.]\d{2})|([\.]\d{2})|()|\s*)$
```

It requires any decimal number to have two decimal places, but it does accept either 0.99 or .99 as an example.

If you want to allow users to enter in 9 or 9.0 or 9.01 (that is, not force the user to enter in two decimal places) you can just modify the above like this:

```
^((\d+([\.]\d{0,2})*)|([\.]\d{0,2})|()|\s*)$
```

It is just setting the quantifiers to {0,2} instead of {2}, and making the existence of decimals places optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*(?:[+-]?\d*\.\d{2})?\s*$
```

matches a number with exactly two decimal places, optionally surrounded by whitespace, or the empty/whitespace only string.

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `^(\s+)|(([+-])?\d+[,\.]\d{2})|()|(null)$`

Comment: The scope of the alternation is wrong, and the empty string doesn't match. Also, `.99` would be rejected although it's a valid float. Same for `-1.23`.

Comment: Why is `0.99` not a valid float? Also, the scope of the alternation is still wrong. All those parentheses are misplaced.

Comment: OK :) - then name *one* language (or calculator model) that does not accept `.99` as a float.

Comment: why are you decide that it will be used in core but not in user interface

Comment: Because, as I read the question, this is used to validate user *input*. I don't want to be restricted to having to write `0.99` if `.99` would also do. When displaying that number, the 0 will be added automatically (provided you have stored it as a float. But you're right, we're at the point where guesswork becomes a problem).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this pattern to handle numbers and empty string scenario.

```
^[-+]?\d*(\.\d{2})?|\s*$
```

Reagrding `NULL`, I have experienced that when we pass `null` as an input in RegEx it throws `ArgumentNullException`. So my recommendation is to validate `NULL` using `!=` operator by matching with `null`:

```
if(str != null && RegEx.IsMatch(str,@"^[-+]?\d*(\.\d{2})?|\s*$"))
   // valid data
```

where:

str = string that contains data validating

Above pattern will also allow: **-.00** or **-0.00** as validate decimals.